# Using ServiceWorker to intercept and redirect requests

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I've been asked to create a service worker which will have the ability to intercept requests and redirect them to stored mock data. I have never done something like this before so I am struggling a bit. The service worker is activated when testMode=true is added to the URL. I have 2 files for dealing with. This is what I have so far:

TestMode.ts

```
class TestMode {
    constructor() {
        if (!this.isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
            console.log('Browser does not support service workers');
            return;
        }

        this.init();
    }

    private init(): void {
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('planner-worker/js/worker.min.js')
            .then(this.handleRegistration)
            .catch((error) => { throw new Error('Service Worker registration failed: ' + error.message); });

        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
            // event is a MessageEvent object
            console.log(`The service worker sent me a message: ${event.data}`);
        });

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then( registration => {
            if (!registration.active) {
                console.log('failed to communicate')

                return;
            }

            registration.active.postMessage("Hi service worker");
        });
    }

    private handleRegistration(registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration): void {
        registration.update();

        console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
    }

    private isEnabled(): boolean {
        return locationService.hasParam('testMode');
    }
}

export default new TestMode();
```

serviceWorker.ts

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'mockData-cache';

const MOCK_DATA: Record<string, string> = {
    '/units/all?availability=Active&roomTypeHandle=kitchens': 'mock-data/unitData.json',
    '/frontal-ranges/kitchens?' : 'mock-data/kitchensData.json',
    '/carcase-ranges/?availability=Active&roomTypeHandle=kitchens' : 'mock-data/carcaseRangesData.json'
};


self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    console.log('Attempting to install service worker and cache static assets');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(cache => {
                return cache.addAll(Object.values(MOCK_DATA));
            })
    );
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('Claiming control');
    return self.clients.claim();
});
self.addEventListener( "fetch", event => {
    console.log('WORKER: Fetching', event.request);
});
```

What I have so far works, the service worker is registered and that mock data json files are stored in the cache.

What I am not sure what to do is when a certain request is made, the service worker will use the mock data stored in the cache instead.

For example, how can I get it so that when the request is made for: /units/all?availability=Active&roomTypeHandle=kitchens the service worker will redirect to mock-data/unitData.json in the cache instead?

I hope I've made sense, any help would be really appreciated, this is all new to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic around handling incoming requests and generating responses (either from the cache, network, or some combination of the two) needs to be implemented in your [`fetch` event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent).

Here's how I'd structure your `fetch` handler given your cache contents and use case:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Using a URL object will make routing easier.
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  const pathAndQuery = url.pathname + url.search;

  if (pathAndQuery in MOCK_DATA) {
    const cacheKey = MOCK_DATA[pathAndQuery];
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(cacheKey, {
        cacheName: CACHE_NAME,
      })
    );
  }

  // If pathAndQuery isn't in MOCK_DATA, then respondWith()
  // won't be called, and the default network behavior will
  // be used for this request.
});
```

You might be able to use a library like https://mswjs.io/ as an alternative to writing this by hand, but that's the general idea if you decide to do it yourself.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, that's really helpful :)